# C# pdfviewer memoryleak

Tags: c#, pdf, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I worked on an application that uses the [PDFViewer component](https://code.google.com/p/pdfviewer-win32/)
 and big PDFs(>85Kb, that maybe affect to the LOH), and I faced with the problem of memoryleak in my app after I integrated it.

Inter alia I supposed the LOH fragmentation and GC weak references. It has no effect:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
```

despite it should collect the heap of generation 2.

By the profilers, perfmon and process explorers I detected, that in every iteration of (create new PDFViewer)/(remove old PDFViewer) we have the same increasing of pagefile, virtual memory and working set. Also size of LOH isn't increasing, but generation 2 heap size is increasing.

I didn't have a opportunity of attract the external assistance because my app is hard and big, but now I detected the same problem in PDFViewer application, that you can download at link above. There is a memory increasing, when I actively resize the window. And when I open other pdf or reopen current pdf, memory isn't collect despite open pdf calles disposing of old pdf:

```
_pdfDoc.Dispose();
_pdfDoc = null;
GC.Collect()
```

has no effect too.

CLR pulled my leg, and I broked a whole my head for find a reason.

Comment: Next time please be more sensitive about formatting..

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: Can you download and see the memoryleak in this app?

Answer (score 0):

By having the line `_pdfDoc.Dispose();` it is not garanteed that the line is called. If there is any error or a return statement before this line. The dispose is not called. Put the _pdfDoc in a `using(...){ ... }`  construction will reduce the change of lose ends.

The way the mesure your management is not so reliable. You can better use a memory profiler to see which object there are in memory after a long periode of running.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a viewer app, it should be converting PDF commands to a raster representation.Most likely using Image class as a canvas. When you talk about active resizing and memory usage increase I think about non-disposed Bitmaps or other GDI resources. Check out that code.

Comment: I thought so too, but I checked PDFViewer app about GDI resources leak via Bear and GDInspector, and it is free of GDI leaks.